# The scope of Require

Tags: ruby, scope, conceptual

I am having trouble accessing a module I declared in another file, and I am wondering if I have this right conceptually. Let me explain.

## If I have file a, b and c setup like so

File a

```
module HelloWorld
  def greet
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

File b

```
require "a"
```

File c

```
require "b"
include HelloWorld

puts greet
```

So it's `a -> b -> c`, will this work?

## Now what if I do it this way

File a

```
module HelloWorld
  def greet
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

File b

```
include HelloWorld

puts greet
```

File c

```
require "a"
require "b"
```

Would that change anything? It seems to me, gems - once required - are accessible no matter what file, but I am having trouble accessing modules in the second scenario. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE: I tested both scenarios, and they both work, which leads me to believe this is not a conceptual problem, but a bug in my code. I am going to work on debugging the project.**

Comment: There is a bug in the code noted in one of the answers. I did not add `./` for the requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to run your code I get the following error message

```
$ ruby c.rb
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- a (LoadError)
  from /Users/Sonna/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from c.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

It is simply saying that it uses the [Kernel's require method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require)
it cannot find the `a.rb` file and then raises and `LoadError` exception.

In order to require the file you can use the [Kernal's `require_relative` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative)

```
require_relative "a"
require_relative "b"
```

and it will a those `a` & `b` files relative to the `c` file.

Or you can add the following lines of code to your `c.rb` file, which is a
common convention used in Ruby Gems to load their custom scripts/libraries

```
current_directory = File.expand_path("../", __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(current_directory) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(current_directory)
```

This will add the current directory `../` from the current file `__FILE__`,
expand it to be an aboslute path of said current directory and add it to the
existing Load Path global variable; e.g.

```
puts $LOAD_PATH
# => ["~/Projects/ruby/stackoverflow_questions/the_scope_of_require",
#     "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0",
#     "~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15"]
```

Which `require` internally uses to find by filename, if it is not given an
absolute path

> If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be searched for
>   in the directories listed in `$LOAD_PATH ($:)`.
>
> -- [Kernel's require method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

So when I run you code again I see the following

```
$ ruby c.rb
hello world
```

It should be noted that

> A file will not be loaded again if its path already appears in `$"`. For
>   example, `require 'a'; require './a'` will not load `a.rb` again.
>
> -- [Module: Kernel (Ruby 2_4_0)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

So as long as one of your `require` methods occur once before one of the methods in
that file are called, it should work; so both of your examples will work (as
long as either the directory the sit is added to the `$LOAD_PATH` or you use
`require_relative` instead)

Comment: I actually noticed this a minute ago when testing it myself. [Here is the actual code](https://github.com/space-hanger/apollo-8). So I have `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and it has both `require "./app/helpers/helpers"` and `require "./app/models/user"`. When I try and access the module from `app/helpers/helpers` in the application controller it works, but when try from `app/models/user` it fails. I fixed it by adding `require "./app/helpers/helpers"` to `app/models/user`, but I should not need to do this. Conceptually this matches scenario b.

Comment: Sorry I probably should have just posted the original source code in the question.

Comment: Looking at sample app code it looks the 'send_text' helper method is causing the pain point your describe. I would argue "is it a good idea to send an SMS every time you set the 'phone' attribute on an User model (especially if the model has not been save yet)?". Also, it seems like you already use 'send_text' on resend verify code, but could use it on create or update of the user controller actions (or in a user form object save method, if you are familiar with them) instead of an API call from the model. It really depends and is up to you where you call within your application.

Comment: Even if I remove the `send_text` call in the user model it still gets mad. I am getting this error `NameError: uninitialized constant User::Helpers`. If I add `require "./app/helpers/helpers"` then everything works fine. It almost seems like I am loading the files in the wrong order and something is not defined before it gets called, but I triple checked my requires in my application controller.

Comment: The 'NameError: uninitialized constant User::Helpers' error would be caused by the 'include Helpers' line since there is no longer a Helpers module being required and there is no class/module within the User class namespace called Helpers. Otherwise, I could not see if there was an explict call for 'User::Helpers' elsewhere in the application

Comment: Ok, the issue is only occurring when I run rake commands. I can start the server fine, but when I run `rake db:migrate` it fails. My start command is `thin start -p 3000`. After everything is migrated and I don't need rake, I can run it fine. I just pushed a [new commit](https://github.com/space-hanger/apollo-8/tree/bb4397a27118406cbc49d2659d3510b823d74d7e) with all my local changes. Sorry I had some local changes I had not pushed, so that might have been causing some of the confusion.

Comment: Oh, I'm so dumb, I rarely use rake I totally forgot about the Rakefile. That explains everything. The Rakefile is broken not the app. At least I have a better understanding of how the Ruby scope works now.